# What real numbers are not in $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

Tags: number-theory

The p-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ seems to be an infinite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ but smaller than $\mathbb{R}$, so can you provide any example that are real number but not in the p-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

Comment: In what sense do you mean smaller then $\mathbb{R}$? They have the same cardinality. Neither one can be embedded in the other.

Comment: $\sqrt{-1} \in \mathbb{Q}_5$.

Comment: The answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1246564/are-p-adic-numbers-real-or-not) might be helpful, too.

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb{Q}_p$ and $\mathbb{R}$ aren't really comparable at all in any reasonable fashion; the question you ask doesn't really make sense.

To get a feel for the problems, observe that even some of the simplest questions you might ask are complicated.

For example, $\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}} \in \mathbb{R}$, assuming you take the positive square root of $2$. It's not if you take the negative square root of $2$.

What about in $\mathbb{Q}_7$? It also depends:

- If you took $\sqrt{2} = \ldots 454_7$, then $\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}}$ is in $\mathbb{Q}_7$
- If you took $\sqrt{2} = \ldots 213_7$, then $\sqrt{1 + \sqrt{2}}$ is not in $\mathbb{Q}_7$

Which of these two $7$-adic square roots of $2$ do you consider to be the "same" as the positive real square root of $2$?

So, you see, even for *algebraic* numbers there isn't a good answer to this.

And, while one could imagine making an infinite series of choices fixing which algebraic numbers are $7$-adic and which are not, and similarly for which algebraic numbers are real and which are not... you don't even have a basis for making comparisons when transcendental numbers are involved!

---

In fact, one can prove that there cannot exist any field homomorphisms $\mathbb{Q}_p \to \mathbb{R}$. For example, any such homomorphism would let us define an ordering on $\mathbb{Q}_p$ that makes it an ordered field... but no such ordering exists.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of **algebraic** numbers that are in $\Bbb R$
but not in a given $\Bbb Q_p$. For instance any $\sqrt a$ where $a$ is
a quadratic nonresidue modulo $p$ (when $p$ is odd).